# undefined reference to `SDL_Init', linking SDL to program

Tags: c, sdl

I am beginning to use the SDL library for the first time and I used the apt-get install to download it onto the windows subsystem (Ubuntu). When I make calls to functions from the SDL library and then run the makefile, I am presented with:

```
/home/display.c:13: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/home/display.c:14: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/home/display.c:17: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/home/display.c:19: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
/home/display.c:22: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
/home/display.c:24: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
```

The makefile looks like:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wunused -std=gnu99  -g -O0 -Wpedantic -lpthread -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

I believe the issue is in linking and that the compiler cannot find where SDL is. However, if this were the case, there should be an error stating that #include SDL2/SDL.h cannot be found. Could this be an installation issue or an issue with the way I link SDL in the makefile?

Comment: When using a library you need to understand two separate steps in building a C program: compiling and linking. You will get errors about missing header files if the *compiler* can't find some. What you got is an error from the *linker* that cannot resolve the references to `SDL_...`. Perhaps it needs some help to find the library files, for example `libSDL2.a`.

Answer (score 4):

The order in which I was placing the flags was incorrect. The libraries should be after the .c and .h files.

Comment: Please edit your question, see this little link on the left below your question? Don't add informations and corrections as an answer.

Comment: @thebusybee SO encourages self-answering https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer although I am voting to close because the problem is a typo (and question lacked the full linking command to see this).

Comment: @LegendofPedro Oh well, I misunderstood the answer as an addition. +1 for closing.